# How do I add two UILabel to a single TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm making a message when the TableView is empty, this is code :

```
        let emptyLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width:     self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
        let emptyLabel2=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))


        emptyLabel.text = "no reminder added yet"
        emptyLabel.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
        emptyLabel.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        emptyLabel2.text = "you add by going back to the homescreen"
        emptyLabel2.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
        emptyLabel2.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)
        emptyLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel2
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        return 0
```

It works, but how do I add emptyLabel2 beneath the emptyLabel. I want to use the defined label properties.

Comment: it overlaps both the labels.

Comment: I've changed the "y:" value, that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add your 2 labels to the superview, with emptyLabel2 on top of emptyLabel, all you need to do is this:

```
self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel)
self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel2)
```

They will be added in the order you call `addSubview`.

If you are asking about how to define the `frame` so that they show one before the next, you need to modify how you are initializing.  Something like this (for example):

```
let emptyLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 20))
let emptyLabel2=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 20))
self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel)
self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel2)
```

In reality you may want to find a better way to set the size, or just make 1 label with `attributedText` so that you do not need 2 labels.

Comment: it overlaps both the labels. How do I move them separate ?

Comment: How can I add a UIImage to the tableView ?

Comment: @S.Verma Same deal - Just keep subviews in the same way.  Do you understand how the `CGRect` works?  Check out the docs if not.

Comment: @S.Verma Also, why not use Storyboard?  That makes it so that you don't have to do the math calculations for layout.

Comment: But we cant use `CGRect` with UIImage !!

Comment: @S.Verma You can never just add `UIImage` to a view - you need to add `UIImageView`, which DOES have a `CGRect` initializer, and add the `UIImage` to that once it's instantiated.  `imageView.image = image`, etc.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any idea why  `self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel2)` &
            `self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel)` makes my text pixelated ?